# Почему мои функции не делают вычислений ? VS код без ошибок

Tags: c++

//Нужно сделать перегруженные функции, код работает, вычисления не делает

```
const double PI = 3.1415;
double vol(double rad);
double vol(double rad, double hei);

int main() 
{
    int i;
    cout << "enter 0 or 1 for fir or sec func" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    if (i == 0)
        double vol(double rad);
    if (i == 1)
        double vol(double rad, double hei);
    return 0;
}
double vol(double rad)
{
    cout << "ent rad" << endl;
    cin >> rad;
    return (4 * PI * rad * 3) / 3;
}
double vol(double rad, double hei)
{
    cout << "rad & hei" << endl;
    cin >> rad;
    cin >> hei;
    return PI * rad * 2 * hei;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В данном if-предложении

```
if (i == 0)
    double vol(double rad);
if (i == 1)
    double vol(double rad, double hei);
```

вы повторно объявляете две функции внутри этого if-предложения. Никакого эффекта эти объявления функций не имеют.

Очевидно имелся в виду вызов этих функций.

Правильно программа могла бы выглядеть, например, следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>

const double PI = 3.1415;
double vol(double rad);
double vol(double rad, double hei);

int main() 
{
    int i;
    std::cout << "enter 0 or 1 for fir or sec func" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> i;

    if (i == 0)
    {
        double rad;

        std::cout << "ent rad" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> rad;
        std::cout << vol(rad) << std::endl;
    }
    if (i == 1)
    {
        double rad, hei;

        std::cout << "rad & hei" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> rad;
        std::cin >> hei;
        std::cout << vol(rad, hei) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

double vol(double rad)
{
    return (4 * PI * rad * 3) / 3;
}
double vol(double rad, double hei)
{
    return PI * rad * 2 * hei;
}
```

Comment: всем спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

Странно, что это вообще компилируется.

Дело в том, что `double vol(double rad);` — предварительное описание функции `vol`, а не вызов.

Вам нужно просто вызвать функции (они у вас уже предварительно описаны выше).